# How do you find a Plantera’s bulb on Terraria mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have defeated most of the bosses on IOS or Mobile Terraria, but still haven’t found the bulb. I would really want to know how to find it on mobile.

Comment: According to the [wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera%27s_Bulb), you need to have defeated at least one of the [mechanical bosses](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanical_boss) for the bulbs to spawn, have you done this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Finding Plantera's bulb is the same for all platforms.

1. You'll first want to see the text 'The Jungle grows restless...' - this green text is how you'll know for sure that Plantera's bulb exists in the world. Kill a mechanical boss to see it (on PC, kill all 3 mechanical bosses).
2. Head to the Jungle, and simply scour the area for the bulb.

There isn't a particular 'trick' to finding one. Simply explore the Jungle biome and you'll eventually run into one. When you do go exploring, it might be helpful to clear the overgrowth and place torches so you know where you've already explored.

Comment: bonus; the bulb looks like a pink flower blossom thing. there have been times where i missed it because i didn't know that.